# Continuous Deployment of builds onto servers from build server

Tags: continuous-integration, ansible, continuous-deployment

I'm using ansible to deploy and install builds on to my servers, but I have to feed Ansible with build name, to grab it and deploy. I would like to close this loop since I have to deploy the builds thrice a day. Is there a tool to do this so that everytime it sees a new build it will automatically invoke the ansible playbook. Or should I go ahead and write my own tool to do this. I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible itself can't do this for you.
But actually there are zillion of other options available: from simple crontab script to complete CI/CD tools such as Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I have used jenkins for a while and I can confirm that Jenkins can do that for you.

Once a commit is done, can it compile your solution and deploy to required environment